# SharePoint SE not able to send automated emails

Tags: email, smtp, sharepoint

I have configured in SharePoint Administration the outgoing emails to an SMTP Server on Port 25.

The SMTP Server is a default setup with anonymous authentication which is the same on SharePoint, and is the install you get with windows server.

When I test SharePoint against a timer job, no emails are appearing on SMTP Server. So, looking at the logs on the SharePoint server, I noticed in the following:

Claims Authentication Context has no SMTP/UPN claims.

I am not sure if this is a coincidence or a  symptom.

So, what else do I need to do to get SharePoint SE to send an email which I can see evidence of on my SMTP Server?